# AWS EC2 pricing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am planning to start with small EC2 RESERVED instance with 3 year commitment. If in between I upgrade it to Large instance; will I be able to use my upfront payment I made for small instance ?

Comment: How is that a programming question?

Comment: Try their [support](https://aws.amazon.com/support/)

Comment: I could see many pricing questions here related to AWS hence I posted this question.

Comment: Did you try asking on their forums? Or calling customer service?

Comment: Yes I have. I posted it here; because this can be a very generic question developers will be having. In a way all AWS questions can be asked on AWS forums; but still we have loads of questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** You cannot apply any payment on a reserved instance to another reserved instance.  Once you have made the purchase you get the discounted rate for an instance that matches the exact instance type, operating system, availability zone.  There are no refunds (though billing has been known to make exceptions immediately after a purchase).

**Tip:** Did you know that you can run instances on EC2 without purchasing a reserved instance?  Thinking reserved instances are required is a common misconception based on the wording used in the AWS documentation.

**Advice:** Based on your question, I recommend you do not purchase any reserved instance for now, much less a 3yr reserved instance.  Wait to see how your instance works on demand and later decide if you believe you will be running it for a year or three.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from AWS Support:

> Reserved Instances are tied to a particular instance type, operating
>   system and availability zone. In order to take advantage of the lower
>   hourly rate, your running Amazon EC2 instances must match the instance
>   type, OS, and Availability Zone as specified when the Reserved
>   Instance was purchased. Since Reserved instance purchases are
>   non-refundable and non-transferable we are not able apply your upfront
>   cost to another reserved instance purchase, or change your reserved
>   instance to cover a large instance.